# How do I check for continuous range of values in each row of pandas dataframe effectively?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose we have pandas dataframe which looks like this one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'A': [0, 0, 1, 0],
        'a': list('aaaa'),
        'B': [1, 0 , 0, 1],
        'b': list('bbbb'),
        'C': [1, 1, 0, 1],
        'c': list('cccc'),
        'D': [0, 1, 0, 1],
        'd': list('dddd')},
        index=[1, 2, 3, 4])
```

The output would be:

```
   A  a  B  b  C  c  D  d
1  0  a  1  b  1  c  0  d
2  0  a  0  b  1  c  1  d
3  1  a  0  b  0  c  0  d
4  0  a  1  b  1  c  1  d
```

So now I want to get rows of this data frame which contains at least for example two zeros sequentially in columns `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`.
For dataframe above the rows with index 2 and 3 are satisfy this conditions: columns `A`, `B` of second row contains zeros, and columns `B`, `C` is enough for third row.

And the method of finding such sequence should work if I want to find three or more sequential zeros.

So eventually I want to have boolean Series which should looks like:

```
1 false
2 true
3 true
4 false
```

to use that Series as mask for original dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

Select the numeric columns, then use `shift` to compare:

```
u = df.select_dtypes(np.number).T
((u == u.shift()) & (u == 0)).any()

1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Ok, but if I will want to find three or more zeros?

Comment: @Alex-droidAD In that case, your question should have explicitly stated "I would like a solution that can look for any number of consecutive zeros, not just two." Please edit your question and I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Data set up from cs95

```
u = df.select_dtypes(np.number).T

(u.rolling(2).sum()==0).any()
Out[404]: 
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks for point out to `select_dtypes` method. I didn't know about it.
But I have remark: rolling `sum` could give wrong result if there would be negative numbers.
And a question: why do I need `any` method at the end?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas' apply function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and define your own function checking your condition as follows:

```
# columns you want to check. Note they have to be in the right order!!
columns = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

# Custom function you apply over df, takes a row as input
def zeros_condition(row):
    # loop over the columns.
    for n in range(len(columns)-1): 
        # return true if 0s in two adjacent columns, else false
        if row[columns[n]] == row[columns[n+1]] == 0:
            return True
    return False

result = df.apply(zeros_condition, axis=1)
```

result is:

```
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: I thought about `apply` method, but have doubt if loop over columns wold be effective.
And by the way, your function `zeros_condition` doesn't columns variable. You will get error.

Comment: @Alex-droidAD apply loops over the rows, the columns are not an argument in this case but they're a list defined outside. It runs fine for me, what's your error?